# Using .UI Files in Mac App Bundles (PyQt5)

Tags: macos, user-interface, py2app, pyqt5, pyuic

I'm using .ui files (from Qt Designer) with Python 3.4 and PyQt5. It works fine if I run it from source, but when I try to use py2app to compile my program into a Mac app package, the program crashes with a big long exception list (https://bpaste.net/show/dad41724b653). Does anyone know what I need to put in my app package to get it to work?
edit: found this 
objc[17603]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both /Applications/Assemble Next/new code/dist/Assemble Next.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets and /Applications/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Please edit the "big long exception list" into your question.

Comment: The list is waay too long to put directly into the question, but here's a permanent paste: https://bpaste.net/show/dad41724b653